# What is the $n$-th sequence for the following expression?

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

We know that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i = n(n+1)/2$$

Similarly, I want to find out an explicit expression for the following sum:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n(i+1)$$

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Hint:
$$
\sum (i+1) = \sum i + \sum 1
$$

Comment: Have you written out any test cases?

Comment: Separate it into two.  $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(i+1) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n i + \sum\limits_{i=1}^n 1$

Comment: How many ones are there.

Comment: @Randall No, I haven't

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah I don't get you

Comment: To explain a bit more about what we are suggesting to do... Recognize that $(a_1+b_1)+(a_2+b_2)+(a_3+b_3)+\dots+(a_n+b_n)$ can be reorganized due to the commutativity and associativity of addition to get $(a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n)+(b_1+b_2+\dots+b_n)$.  Be warned however that although this works for finite sums, shenanigans can happen when talking about infinite sums.

Comment: So here, you have $(1+1)+(2+1)+(3+1)+\dots+(n+1) = \underbrace{(1+2+3+\dots+n)}_{n~\text{terms}} + \underbrace{(1+1+1+\dots+1)}_{n~\text{terms}}$.  The stuff in the first pair of parentheses you say you know how to simplify.  The second stuff in the second pair of parentheses is jut adding $1$ to itself $n$ times that you should also be able to easily simplify.

Answer (score 1):

For the sequence :$$\sum_{i=1}^n(i+1)$$

We can write,

$$\sum_{i=1}^n(i) + \sum_{i=1}^n(1) $$

From, $$\sum_{i=1}^n(i) = n(n+1)/2$$ , we can write

$$n(n+1)/2+n$$

Hence, 
 $$\sum_{i=1}^n(i+1) = ( n^2+ 3n) /2$$

nth-term of the sequence : $$n+1$$